# Dynamic rowspan for each row in a v-for loop

Tags: vue.js, html-table, vuejs3, v-for

Provided the data in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/lolsokje/pen/zYJExog), I need to be able to render the table as shown in the same codepen. As shown, every driver can have one or more teams attached to them. The position and points should be only shown once, while for each team the name and number used should be shown.

For some reason I can't get my head wrapped around this one. I've currently got the following loop, which displays the position and points properly according to the amount of teams, but how can I get the teams to show properly?

```
<template>
    ...
    <tbody>
    <tr v-for="driver in standings" :key="driver.position">
        <td :rowspan="getRowspan(driver)">{{ driver.position }}</td>
        <td>?</td>
        <td>?</td>
        <td :rowspan="getRowspan(driver)">{{ driver.points }}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
    const getRowspan = (driver): int => {
        return Object.keys(driver.teams).length;
    };
</script>
```

I've messed around with `v-for` loops on `template`s, but can never get the result I need.

Answer (score 0):

I would group by position and then use `v-if` on the spanning rows, so that they are only drawn for the first team:

```js
const { createApp } = Vue;

const drivers = [
    {
      "position": 1,
      "points": 100,
      "teams": [
        {
          "name": "One",
          "number": 1
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "position": 2,
      "points": 80,
      "teams": [
        {
          "name": "Two",
          "number": 3
        },
        {
          "name": "Three",
          "number": 6
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "position": 3,
      "points": 60,
      "teams": [
        {
          "name": "Four",
          "number": 10
        },
        {
          "name": "Five",
          "number": 11
        },
        {
          "name": "Six",
          "number": 12
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

const App = {
  setup(){
    return {drivers}
  }
}
const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="app">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>pos</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>number</th>
        <th>points</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <template v-for="driver in drivers" :key="driver.position">
      <tr v-for="team in driver.teams" :key="team.name">
      
        <td v-if="team === driver.teams[0]" :rowspan="driver.teams.length">{{ driver.position }}</td>
        <td>{{team.name}}</td>
        <td>{{team.number}}</td>
        <td v-if="team === driver.teams[0]" :rowspan="driver.teams.length">{{ driver.points }}</td>
        
      </tr>
    </template>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>


<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is the bit you're looking for:

```html
<template v-for="{ points, teams, position } in drivers" :key="position">
  <tr v-for="({ name, number }, key) in teams" :key="key">
    <td v-if="!key" :rowspan="teams.length" v-text="position" />
    <td v-text="number" />
    <td v-text="name" />
    <td v-if="!key" :rowspan="teams.length" v-text="points" />
  </tr>
</template>
```

See it working:

```js
const { createApp } = Vue;
const drivers = [
  {
    position: 1,
    points: 100,
    teams: [
      {
        name: "One",
        number: 1,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    position: 2,
    points: 80,
    teams: [
      {
        name: "Two",
        number: 3,
      },
      {
        name: "Three",
        number: 6,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    position: 3,
    points: 60,
    teams: [
      {
        name: "Four",
        number: 10,
      },
      {
        name: "Five",
        number: 11,
      },
      {
        name: "Six",
        number: 12,
      },
    ],
  },
];

createApp({ setup: () => ({ drivers }) }).mount("#app")
```

```css
td { vertical-align: top }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.47/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Points</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <template v-for="{points, teams, position } in drivers" :key="position">
        <tr  v-for="({name, number}, key) in teams" :key="key">
          <td v-if="!key" :rowspan="teams.length" v-text="position"></td>
          <td v-text="number"></td>
          <td v-text="name"></td>
          <td v-if="!key" :rowspan="teams.length" v-text="points"></td>
        </tr>
      </template>
    </tbody>
  </table>  
</div>
```

---

Or you could extract `Driver.vue`:

```html
<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue"
export default defineComponent({ props: ["points", "teams", "position"] })
</script>
<template>
  <tr v-for="({ name, number }, key) in teams" :key="key">
    <td v-if="!key" :rowspan="teams.length" v-text="position" />
    <td v-text="number" />
    <td v-text="name" />
    <td v-if="!key" :rowspan="teams.length" v-text="points" />
  </tr>
</template>
```

And use it as:

```
<tbody>
  <Driver v-for="driver in drivers" v-bind="driver" :key="driver.position" />
</tbody>
```

Test:

```js
const { createApp, defineComponent } = Vue

const Driver = defineComponent({
  props: ["position", "points", "teams"],
  template: '#driver-tpl'
})

const drivers = [
  {
    position: 1,
    points: 100,
    teams: [
      {
        name: "One",
        number: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    position: 2,
    points: 80,
    teams: [
      {
        name: "Two",
        number: 3
      },
      {
        name: "Three",
        number: 6
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    position: 3,
    points: 60,
    teams: [
      {
        name: "Four",
        number: 10
      },
      {
        name: "Five",
        number: 11
      },
      {
        name: "Six",
        number: 12
      }
    ]
  }
]

createApp({
  setup: () => ({ drivers }),
  components: { Driver }
}).mount("#app")
```

```css
td { vertical-align: top }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.47/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Points</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr
        is="vue:driver"
        v-for="driver in drivers"
        :key="driver.position"
        v-bind="driver"
      />
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<template id="driver-tpl">
  <tr v-for="({ name, number }, key) in teams" :key="key">
    <td v-if="!key" :rowspan="teams.length" v-text="position" />
    <td v-text="number" />
    <td v-text="name" />
    <td v-if="!key" :rowspan="teams.length" v-text="points" />
  </tr>
</template>
```

---

*Side note:* (somewhat interesting, yet outside the answer's scope) -
I had to use `<tr is="vue:Driver" />` instead of `<Driver />` to prevent the browser from moving `<Driver />` out of `<table />` before Vue has a chance to parse it.

Possible fixes:

- `<tr is="vue:driver" >`, suggested by @MoritzRingler in comments
- place app's template in a `<script type="x-template">`
- use a `<template/>` in-place, which is valid (almost) anywhere (not sure if valid outside of `<html>` or `<body />`, though):

```html
<tbody>
  <template v-for="driver in drivers" :key="driver.position">
    <Driver v-bind="driver" />
  </template>
</tbody>
```

I found out about the cause and the fixes by opening [an issue](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/7854) on Vue's repo, graciously explained by [@skirtle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8583563/skirtle).

Comment: As to your side note, I think that's the issue described in [element placement restrictions](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#element-placement-restrictions). They propose to use `<tr is="vue:driver" v-bind="driver"></tr>`

Comment: Pretty cool find, @Moritz. Thanks!